# how do I access this javascript element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have an array in PHP that I want to edit in Javascript.

I pass it from php to javascript like this:

```
var allPartsList = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($all); ?>');
```

if I `console.log(all);` I see this:

[image]

What I'm ultimately trying to do is find lines that have been passed from PHP where one of the two fields, either `partNumber` or `supplier` is blank, then add values back into the array based on values the user has submitted.  The values below are supplied by a checkbox that the user clicks on.

I have the syntax for a loop statement down:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="supplierCheck"]').change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {

       var supplier   = this.dataset.supplier;
       var partNumber = this.dataset.partnumber;
       var x          = this.dataset.x;

       for (var i = 0; i < allPartsList.length; i++) {       
          if (allPartsList[i][0] == x) {            
            allPartsList[i][2] = supplier; //replace whatever supplier is with the supplier the user has chosen
          }       
       }      
     console.log(allPartsList);
     }
 });
```

my for loop, however, is failing, because I don't know how to access the various elements of `allPartsList`.  If I do `console.log(allPartsList[0]` I see

```
Object {line: 0, supplier: "a", partNumber: "asdf"}
```

so I'm not sure if it's even an array that I can step through.  I seem to be able to access `allPartsList[0]`, but I can't access any elements of `[0]`, like `allPartsList[0][0]`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `allPartsList` is a one dimensional array of objects, with string keys not numerical, so `allPartsList[i][0]` is not correct.

To update the properties in your loop, you can do:

```
allPartsList[i].supplier = supplier;
```

Or to read a property:

```
console.log( allPartsList[i].supplier );
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `x` check, it appears you want to test the index, so in that case, test against `i` like

```
if (i == x) {
```

---

Side note: your initial JSON decode is not necessary. The PHP will produce JSON which happens to be valid JavaScript as well. So you can simplify to:

```
var allPartsList = <?php echo json_encode($all); ?>;
```

Comment: so use a dot.  Thank you so much!  So simple.. worked perfectly :)  Yeah - I didn't want to paste the entire html and php that would have made the context easier to understand, cause it's a lot of code (and kind of pointless to the question.)  It does exactly what I want it to though now. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to your log, allPartsList is an array of objects. You can access an object's properties using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Here's how you would access the supplier property of the first object in the array: `allPartsList[0].supplier`

So try changing your for loop to something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allPartsList.length; i++) {       
  if (allPartsList[i].line == x) {            
    allPartsList[i].supplier = supplier; 
  }  
}
```